# swift 3 prototype cell current row button

Tags: swift, uitableview

I try to do a to-do app. 
I use prototype cells and I'm currently running into a problem that when I'm pressing the button, nothing happens

so far this works to get the row of the button.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

    let task = tasks[indexPath.row]


    cell.uncheckbox.tag = indexPath.row
    cell.uncheckbox.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.Test), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    cell.textField.isEnabled = false
    cell.importantImage.isHidden = true


    if(task.isImportant){
        cell.textField?.text =  task.name!
        cell.importantImage.isHidden = false;
    }else{
        cell.textField?.text = task.name!
    }

    return cell;
}

@IBAction func Test(sender: UIButton)
{
    let row = sender.tag

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell") as! TableViewCell

    print(row)
    print(row == 0)
    if(row == 0){

         cell.textField?.text =  "change the text"
    }



}
```

the problem is , once I press the button nothing happens to the current cell. I guess it's still not set into the right row.

When I just print the row and then press the button, I get the right value from the button

Comment: found another solution ! 
thanks for help

Comment: can you show your solution? otherwise it is useless for others

Answer (score 0):

found a way to do it :

i called the button within the TableViewCell class

```
 // when i press the add button it checks all buttons
@IBAction func testing(_ sender: Any) {
    if(isBoxClicked == true)
    {
        uncheckbox.setImage(checkBox, for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        isBoxClicked = false
    }else{
       uncheckbox.setImage(uncheckBox, for: UIControlState.normal)
         self.textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        isBoxClicked = true
    }
}
```

and inside the vieClass i used this

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
```

cell.testing(cell.uncheckbox)

```
  return cell;
}
```